# vscode surround text with snippet cursor placement

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Following the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74064202/608368) post I'm able to insert a snippet around some selected text. As seen in @Mark's demo after completing the insert the cursor is left in two places. The line/lines all end with a newline.

original:

```
cube([10, 10, 10]);
```

what I want:

```
difference() {
    cube([10, 10, 10]);
    |
}
```

what I get:

```
|difference() {
    cube([10, 10, 10]);

|}
```

Here is the snippet code I'm using:

```
"body": [
    "${1:${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^([ \\t]*)[\\s\\S]*$/$1/}}difference() {",
    "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(.*?)$(\\r?\\n)?/\t$1$2/gm}",  // note the 'g' flag !!!
    "$1$0}\n"
],
```

Based on the snippet code it makes sense that the $0 point is underneath the second cursor. So how can I remove the last newline in the selected text so I can put $0 before that last newline? I realize I may have to type a `tab` to get to the position of the $0. For now I'm just making sure I don't select the last newline, but I'd like to just be able to triple click and drag the cursor down to select the lines.

Comment: the snippet is asking content for `${1}`, you don't need to add `${TM_SELECTED_TEXT` in `${1}`, you see 2 cursors because you have repeated `${1}` at the end

Comment: The $1 contains the leading tabs. I'm using that to justify the text correctly. So the "$1\t$0\n$1}" is adding the correct number of tabs for the blank line for the first $1 and for the } for the second $1.